# Using onEnabled method with QnAMakerRecognizer

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I'm trying to use the `onEnabled` method with QnAMakerRecognizer, so that I can have multiple QnAMakerRecognizers and can choose which to enable and which to disable. I've tried following this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/feature-onEnabled/app.js) and tried something similar but I get an error saying:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).onEnabled is not a function

How do I use the `onEnable` method correctly?

Sample code:

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

var qnarecognizer1 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: knowledgeId, 
    subscriptionKey: subscriptionId,
    qnaThreshold:0.3,
    top:1})
.onEnabled(function (session, callback) {
        // Check to see if this recognizer should be enabled
        if (session.conversationData.useqna1) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(null, false);
        }
    });

var qnarecognizer2 = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: knowledgeId, 
    subscriptionKey: subscriptionId,
    qnaThreshold:0.3,
    top:1})
.onEnabled(function (session, callback) {
        // Check to see if this recognizer should be enabled
        if (session.conversationData.useqna2) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(null, false);
        }
    });

var intentrecognizer = new builder.IntentDialog();

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [intentrecognizer, qnarecognizer1, qnarecognizer2] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('qna', [
    function (session, args, next) {
            args.entities.forEach(function(element) {
            session.send(element.entity);     
        }, this);           
    }
]);

intents.matchesAny([/hi/i, /main menu/i], [
    function (session) {
   builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Hi, What would you like to ask me about?", ["Service1","Service2"],{ listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});

    },

       function (session, result) {
    var selection = result.response.entity;
           switch (selection) {
               case "Service1":
                    session.conversationData.useqna1 = true;
        session.conversationData.useqna2 = false;
                    session.send('You can now ask me anything about '+selection+'. Type \'main menu\' anytime to choose a different topic.')
                    session.endConversation();
                    return 

               case "Service2":
                    session.conversationData.useqna1 = false;
        session.conversationData.useqna2 = true;
                    session.send('You can now ask me anything about '+selection+'. Type \'main menu\' anytime to choose a different topic.')
                    session.endConversation();
                    return 

           }
   }

])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QnAMakerRecognizer doesn't implement Bot Builder IntentRecognizer, and it does not have an onEnabled method.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/dc3517bf651c4209926aa3a9f2a4df0654ab1d5a/Node/lib/QnAMakerRecognizer.js

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/070acb410b70312f418d23e032013c4ddf90fdc5/Node/core/lib/dialogs/IntentRecognizer.js

Edit:
I've submitted an issue for this on the BotBuilder-CognitiveServices repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/62

Answer (score 0):

In our project we ended doing something like this as a workaround.

We cloned the recognize prototype function and checked the conversationData boolean for enabling/disabling the recognizer.

Hope it works for you ;)

```
qnaRecognizer.__proto__['_recognize'] = qnaRecognizer.__proto__['recognize']
qnaRecognizer.__proto__.recognize = function (context, cb) {
  if(!context.conversationData || !context.conversationData.ignoreQnARecognizers){
    return qnaRecognizer.__proto__._recognize.apply(this, [context, cb]);
  } else {
    cb(null, null);
  }
}
```